# Comparing how many letters match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, worksheet-function

I'm trying to compare two cells in Excel to retrieve a numeric value, for example:

```
Trial type   Duration    Letters shown   Distracters    Laterality   Response  Full  
 6           80          XZHTEJ          0              Bilateral    TEHZ
```

In that line I would like to compare the letters shown with the response, and return a number for how many are correct. I would like it to have the number 4, as there are four letters typed that match the letters shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA might be more suitable but you have not tagged as such and a formula should work:

```
=IFERROR(FIND(MID(C1,1,1),F1)>0,0)+IFERROR(FIND(MID(C1,2,1),F1)>0,0)+IFERROR(FIND(MID(C1,3,1),F1)>0,0)+IFERROR(FIND(MID(C1,4,1),F1)>0,0)++IFERROR(FIND(MID(C1,5,1),F1)>0,0)+IFERROR(FIND(MID(C1,6,1),F1)>0,0)
```

Comment: Nice approach.  You could also use `ISNUMBER` to swallow the error and return TRUE or FALSE: `=ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(C1,1,1),F1))+ ...`

Comment: @pnuts - might be interested in the less "quick and dirty" solution. I've given it a go below.

Answer (score 1):

@pnuts' answer works if Letters Shown (in C1) is always 6 or fewer characters.

The following will work if Response (in F1) is always 4 or fewer characters:

```
=LEN(C1)-
 LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
     C1,MID(F1,1,1),""),MID(F1,2,1),""),MID(F1,3,1),""),MID(F1,4,1),"")
 )
```

Either method can easily be expanded as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) This worked as you said it would, sorry for not being specific enough, Response can be up to 6 letters.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, here is a solution for any length of response. It also has the advantage of being shorter than the other given solutions (I think)

```
{=SUM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(MID(F1,ROW(INDIRECT("B1:B"&LEN(F1))),1),MID(C1,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(C1))),1),0)),0,1))}
```

It's an array formula so leave out the curly braces and enter the formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

The solution creates two arrays like below

```
Shown      Inputted
 X          T
 Z          E
 H          H
 T          Z
 E
 J
```

And then loops through each of the **Inputted** characters looking for a match in the **Shown** array and returning a 1 if there is a match, otherwise a 0. Finally the `SUM` adds all of the 1's (matches) to give the required result.